# Odoo - Internal Server Error on custom module uninstall

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to make a simple inheritance module so I can add more fields in new Opportunity Form but odoo doesn't like my code. I am pretty new in Odoo and Python so don't blame me :(

mymodule.py:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv 

class crm_lead_mymodule(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    _columns = {
        'product_type' : fields.selection( [('basic', 'Basic'),('pro', 'Pro'),], ),
    }
```

mymodule.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="view_crm_opportunity_mymodule_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">crm.lead.mymodule.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='lead']" position="after">
                <page string="Product Information">
                    <group col="3">
                            <field name="product_type"/>
                    </group>
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

I tried a lot of installs, after changes in my code until I uninstall it and odoo crashed. I am getting "Internal Server error" with the following log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  ...
  ...
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 168, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 593, in _build_model
    original_module = pool[name]._original_module if name in parents else cls._module
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 84, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'crm.lead'
```

Comment: Try to comment `<record id="view_crm_opportunity_mymodule_form" model="ir.ui.view">....</record>` in your view and update module.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar How i can update it? I am not able to login :(

Comment: Ok. Try to comment `record` in view and restart server. Server must to see that errors disappeared.

Comment: By the way updates in python files will be seen ONLY after restart server.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I tried it, restarted the server but same error

Comment: Are you working on local machine?

Comment: Nope... in a VPS! Debian! I restart it via service odoo restart. I am getting the log with tail  /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log

Comment: Do you have backup db before your changes? Or can you have opportunity drop db with all data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99730/discussion-between-alexandros-and-danila-ganchar).

Comment: I've found that removing the module from the addons folder releases the Internal Server error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First what you need it is check `depends` section in your **openerp**.py. This is must be something like that: `'depends': ['base', 'crm'],`. After this try to drop your local db and create new from GUI.

About problem in chat(opportunity button in customers)... In **Sales -> Customers** works form from **base** module. You can use **developer mode** to check it. In this form use `res.partner` object and `base.view_partner_form`.

How to add your fields to this form? Just create test_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="view_partner_form_mymodule_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.partner.mymodule.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page" position="after">
                <page string="Product Information">
                    <!-- your fields here  -->
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

And add your view to **openerp**.py like that:

```
'data': [
     'test_view.xml',
],
```

Be careful! In this view use `res.partner` model, but not `crm.lead`.
Hope this help you!